# Search Bar with API database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, search, axios

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  updateSearch = (e) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey{1234}&query=${data}&number=100`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Search Food..."
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={data}
        />
        <List style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            {this.state.data.map(({ type }) => (
              <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
            ))}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </List>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Hey everyone, I'm trying to build a `SearchBar`, and when I type in the `SearchBar` the variable `query` in the URL should change to what I'm typing, for now when I run it returns nothing.

Link to documentation of the Database: https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Grocery-Products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same state for the data you receive and the value is input in the SearchBar, first create another state to keep the input value and pass that in the URL

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      searchValue: '',
    };
  }

  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({searchValue: value})
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey{1234}&query=${value}&number=100`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Search Food..."
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={searchValue}
        />
        <List style={{ paddingTop: hp("2%") }}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            {this.state.data.map(({ type }) => (
              <Text>{this.state.type.products.title}</Text>
            ))}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </List>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

However, doing this every time the user types is not recommended, you can check out this pattern to debounce the API call for usability https://gist.github.com/simonw/c29de00c20fde731243cbac8568a3d7f

**UPDATE**

Since the API doesn't allow to search for empty value, put a condition to set the data to an empty array when the input is blank

```
  updateSearch = (value) => {
    this.setState({searchValue: value})
    if(value.trim() !== '') {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search?apiKey{1234}&query=${value}&number=100`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        });
    } else {
      setState({data: []})
    }
  };
```

Comment: it now gives me a different `error: undefined is not a function (near'...this.state.data.map')`, sorry for the many questions, I am new to this and still learning.